# Jsoup.connect cannot get correct html contents

Tags: java, jsoup, connect

i use Jsoup to extract specified data from a website,

```
try{
   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example/search/").get();
} catch(IOException){
  System.out.println("error");
}
```

but i'm got failed, and the output is "error".

when i browse with Mozilla,or another browser this address is successfully to load.
Any idea?Please help me..

Best regards

Comment: THe output *of your own error message* is 'error'. If you printed something more useful, such as the exception itself, or its stack trace, you wouldn't be so baffled, and someone else might be able to answer this question. As it is, we can't. When you get an exception, don't just print some message of your own devising and then wonder what happened.

Comment: ok @EJP i will remember your advice, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display the exception message from your `IOException` message, you will see

> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=...

Solution: You need to set the user agent to correspond to the mobile website

```
Document doc = 
     Jsoup.connect("http://m.tokobagus.com/search/province").userAgent
      ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)          
        Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
```

More importantly, remember to display those exception messages:

```
} catch(IOException ioe){
  ioe.printStacktrace();
}
```